# sharing nginx status location with all vhosts in hiera and puppet

Tags: nginx, puppet, hiera

I'm using Jfryman puppet nginx module and I'm trying to enable status location with available vhosts , so my hiera go like this :

```
---
nginx::nginx_vhosts:
  'default':
    www_root: '/www/default'
    listen_port: 8081

  'default2':
    www_root: '/www/default2'
    listen_port: 8082

  'default3':
    www_root: '/www/default3'
    listen_port: 8083

nginx::nginx_locations:
  'status':
    location: '/status'
    vhost: 'default'...."here wanna include more than one vhost"
    stub_status: true
```

is there anyway to say like this location included in these vhosts without duplicating the hiera entries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the [location](https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx/blob/master/manifests/resource/location.pp) type takes only one [vhost](https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx/blob/master/manifests/resource/location.pp#L10-11) parameter and uses it to determine the [target file](https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx/blob/master/manifests/resource/location.pp#L338-339).

To keep things DRY, you will have to refrain from using the `nginx_locations` parameter of the `nginx` class, and declare the `nginx::resource::location` instances yourself.

```
define status_location_for_vhost() {
    nginx::resource::location { "status-for-$name":
        location => '/status',
        vhost    => $name,
        stub_status => true
    }
}
```

Declare on of those for each vhost.

Comment: Thanks for your answer help so much, but just found that there is no need since the status is general for all vhosts, so it doesn't make sense to enable it per host